# Class Object not visible after calling it to a ListBox from an ObservableCollection List. However it still exists and is selectable

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, observablecollection

I am populating a listbox full of Car Objects that are stored on an `Observable Collection`.

I am taking the car details from a LINQ database, making them into Car class objects and storing them to the Observable collection CarList as follows:

```
 var ListQuery = from c in db.Cars
                  select c;

 foreach (var car in ListQuery)
 {
     Car c1 = new Car(car.ID, car.Make, car.Model, car.Size);
     CarList.Add(c1);
 }
```

Below is the Car class including the two string they are to be stored as.

```
    public class Car 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }

        public Car (int id, string make, string model, string size)
        {
            Size = size;
            Make = make;
            Model = model;
            ID = id;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", Make, Model);
        }

        //This method is for displaying the selected listbox Item's details in a textbox.
        public string GetDetails()
        {
            return string.Format("CarID: {0}\nMake: {1}\nModel: {2}\n",
                    ID, Make, Model);

        }
```

Finally, when a button is pressed I populate the listbox with the CarList items.

```
private void btn_Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   lbx_CarList.ItemsSource = CarList;
}
```

The object's fill the list box and are selectable, however they are not visible. I would have thought the `ToString()` method in the class would be what they are displayed as but this is not the case.

Below shows the WPF window and what I see once an item in the listbox is selected.
[When code runs and listbox is populated with Car class objects from CarList Observable Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPzgJ.png)

Would anyone know what I am missing or how to show the object items string? I tried

```
lbx_CarList.ItemsSource = CarList.ToString()
```

and

```
CarList.ToList()
```

but with no avail. so I hope it isn't something obvious I missed. Any help would be great! Thank you.

Edit: Xaml added. There was some extra stuff I took out so only the code relevant to the question remained.

```
<Window x:Class="FinalProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FinalProject"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>

    <Label x:Name="label3" Content="Available Cars" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbx_CarList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="99" Margin="53,210,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="233" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectionChanged="lbx_CarList_SelectionChanged"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbk_CarDetails" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="319,210,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="99" Width="146" ClipToBounds="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="label4" Content="Selected Car" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="319,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.421,-0.115" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Image x:Name="img_Car" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="319,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158"/>

    <Button x:Name="btn_Search" Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="167,159,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btn_Search_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Probably you are missing the path part of your binding. Show XAML as @Eldho has already asked

Comment: Added Xaml above. Thanks guys

Comment: Where is `description` in your model ?

Comment: Well..this is not how you should bind an observablecollection, but at a first look in your listbox you have `DisplayMemberPath="Description"`but I don't see that property in your car class

Comment: Oh my god. I did that at the very beginning of my code when I was filling in the results directly from the database select query I completely forgot about it. I am an idiot. Thanks a million guys, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Instead of GetDetails() method create a read only Description property and it should work. item source setting code should be like this lbx_CarList.ItemsSource = CarList . No need to calling ToList again, as this is observable collection already.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Model` should Implement `[INotifyPropertyChangedInterface][1]`

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}


public class Car
{
    private string _make ;
    public string Make
    {
      get { return _make ; }
      set
      {
         _make = value;
         //This will update each time you set a value to the userinterface
         NotifyPropertyChanged("Make");
      }
  }
}
```

Xaml

```
 <ListView Name="ListView"ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Make}"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

> You can use `Binding` to show the list or use code behind to show the items.
>   Take a look at [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mvvm/info) will bring some idea about Binding how to bind objects in the user interface.